# Retrieving encrypted cookie string value in AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, encryption, cookies

In an ASP.NET web application, I have encrypted a string value and stored the result in the Cookie. Now, I want to retrieve the cookie value in an AngularJS application. 
The problem is I am unable to retrieve the encrypted cookie value in AngularJS.
Anyone got any idea?

The Code that I am using to encrypt the string value into byte array is:

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(string emailId)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(emailId);
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HLCC1PQRSA72017");
        int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] + passwordBytes[passwordShiftIndex]);
            passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % passwordBytes.Length;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Further, I am using ToBase64String() method to convert the byte array into string and store it in the Cookie.

Comment: Please provide JS code snippet you tried to retrieve the cookie.

Comment: I don't think you can count this as properly encrypted in the first place....to the point at which you might as well just store the email id in the header

Comment: This is not an encryption system, this is an attempt at all. You should use a properly tested, well known encryption algorithm instead of trying to do your own

Comment: Furthermore if you need to decrypt it client side, any key you use will be available to an attacker

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Can you suggest some of the encryption algorithm suitable in this scenario.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @the.net-learner Emh... Is there any reason you wouldn't be able to use AES, for example? Do notice that anything you do on the JS client-side will be visible to any attacker, so don't depend on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time and responses friends.
I have used the following code to convert the string value in bytes array:

```
atob(stringValue);
```

Further, I have used the following code to decrypt the byte array and finally obtain the encrypted string:

```
    var str = 'The encrypted byte array'; //Insert here the encrypted byte array value that you have obtained after using the atob function.
    var b = []; // char codes
    var pKey='ABCD39493CDCCD'; //Insert here the password key which was used to encrypt the string.
    var b2=[];
    var passwordIndex= 0;
    var finalString='';

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) 
    {
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        b = b.concat([code]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < pKey.length; ++i) 
    {
        var code2 = pKey.charCodeAt(i);
        b2 = b2.concat([code2]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (b[i] - b2[passwordIndex]);
        passwordIndex = (passwordIndex + 1) % b2.length;
    }

    for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        finalString=finalString+(String.fromCharCode(b[i]));
    }
    return finalString;
```